# change matplotlib axis settings

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

How do I get control over the axis settings of a pyplot plot. I have simply done

```
    pylab.plot(*self.plot_generator(low, high))

    pylab.show()
```

and I get this which is what I want

[image]

but I want the x axis to be at 0 instead of at the bottom. How would I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
# create some data
x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
y = np.cos(2.5*x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y, mfc='orange', mec='orange', marker='.')

# using 'spines', new in Matplotlib 1.0
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

ax.axhline(linewidth=2, color='blue')
ax.axvline(linewidth=2, color='blue')
show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like what I need, along with @Joe Kington's comment

Comment: You can find a more general description on how to use spines in that regard here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html

Comment: Could you explain why `ax.spines` is used here. AFAIK, all the methods `set_position` or `set_color` are member of `matplotlib.spines.Spine` class object. That's confusing.

Comment: That's correct. `ax.spines` is an `OrderedDict` that contains four `Spine` objects: `'left'`, `'right'`, `'top'`, and `'bottom'`.

Comment: The `axhline`, `axvline` commands are not needed here. If one wants to change the linewidth or color of the axes it is better to change the axes properties.

Answer (score 12):

To set start of x-axis to 0:

```
pylab.xlim(xmin=0)
```

To set start of y-axis to 0:

```
pylab.ylim(ymin=0)
```

Put one of these lines (or both if you'd like) after the `pylab.plot` call.