# Add margin in a 2D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How would you add a margin between the axis lines and the actual origin? In 3D scatter, like this [one](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp130/12spring/pca/ShakespeareAlmostComplete.png), the origin of `x = 6` and `y = -10` are not on the same point. How to do the same thing but in a 2D scatter (something similar to the graphic of p. 122 (132 of pdf) in this [matplotlib doc](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs4243/doc/Matplotlib.pdf), where the origin `x = 0` and `y = 0` are not located at the same place).

Answer (score 4):

A margin can be easily added to any plot by supplying the `plt.set_xmargin(m)` with a float between 0 and 1 indicating the relative size of the margin:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig =plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.cos(x)

ax.set_xmargin(0.2)
ax.set_ymargin(0.2)

ax.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Note in practise this needs to be called before `ax.plot(..` as this is when the autoscaling is done. For more information [see here](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins)

Comment: Let's say you would set the `y` limits to `[0,2]`, how would you have the origin `(0,0)` at `(1,1)` (`(1,1)` in your figure correspond to the point `(0,-1)`) in this case? `set_xmargin` and `set_ymargin` doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: That is quite a somewhat different question, but thanks for the additional info. You can achieve this by shifting the axis. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify something for me - what exactly do you mean by origin? The point `0,0` is always the origin regardless of the limits.  In the examples given the different axis simply had different limits or had a margin applied. Do you mean too actually shift the origin so that the point that was at (0,0) is now at (1,1)?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say "shifting axis", as what I want is just a square margin in the bottom left of the figure, so that the origin `(0,0)` in any graph is not as the jonction of the `x` and `y` axis.

Comment: Does [the first answer in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289891/change-matplotlib-axis-settings) look like what you want?

Comment: No. What I [want](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CvehB.png) (the origin `(0,0)` is not where the `x` and `y` axis meet). What I [don't want](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dFML5.png) (here the origin `(0,0)` is where the `x` and `y` axis meet).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45735/discussion-between-greg-and-m-power)