# Set axis origin using PyPlot plot in Julia

Tags: plot, axis, julia

I am completely new to Julia. I am using the PyPlot package in Julia and am just trying to set my x and y axis origin to 0 and 0 respectively. At the moment it just chooses where the origin will be based on the values of the points I'm plotting.

```
plot(x1,y1,".")
xlabel("X1")
ylabel("Y1")
title("First Line")
grid("on")
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.
[change matplotlib axis settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289891/change-matplotlib-axis-settings)

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a matplotlib command together with the Julia equivalent that you actually tried, following the syntax description in the PyCall.jl documentation.

Comment: I am a 100% beginner here and have no idea what you are talking about. What I did is given above. Help!

Comment: I've started using PyPlot.axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]) for this:PyPlot.plot(spacerdata[:Width],spacerdata[:Curvature],".")
PyPlot.xlabel("Width")
PyPlot.ylabel("Curvature")
PyPlot.title("Plot")
PyPlot.grid("on")
PyPlot.axis([0,2,0,4])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using PyPlot in Julia is different than matplotlib in Python. You are looking for the Julia equivalent of setting limits on axis. I've found [this useful github repo](https://gist.github.com/gizmaa/7214002) that might be of use to you.

Here is how you can add custom limits to the y axis:

```
using PyPlot

x1 = rand(50, 1) .* 30 .+ 50
y1 = rand(50, 1) .* 30 .+ 100 

plot(x1, y1)

# get the current axis argument of the plot
ax = gca()

# add new limits from 0 - 100
ax[:set_ylim]([0,100])
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. I get the following error: LoadError: UndefVarError: ax not defined

Comment: You're right! I forgot to assign the axis of the plot to ax. See the edited answer above. Hopefully this will get what you want.

Comment: You can forget about `ax` and just use `ylim(1, 100)`. But this doesn't really answer the original question.

Comment: Thanks niczky12. David I tried your suggestion and it works so I edited your answer niczky12.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for using PyPlot in Julia is a bit different from Python. 
This is a result of the fact that (currently) you cannot use `obj.f()` to access the method (function) `f()` inside an object `obj` in Julia, which PyPlot uses heavily.

To get around this, `obj.f()` in Python is replaced by `obj[:f]()` in Julia; note the `:`.

So `ax.spines` in Python becomes

```
ax[:spines]
```

in Julia.

As noted by the other poster, you must first do `ax = gca()` to store the current axis object in the variable `ax`.

If you do this at the Julia REPL or in a Jupyter notebook, you will see

```
julia> ax = gca()
PyObject <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x31f854550>

julia> ax[:spines]
Dict{Any,Any} with 4 entries:
  "left"   => PyObject <matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x31f854c10>
  "bottom" => PyObject <matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x31f854f50>
  "right"  => PyObject <matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x31f854dd0>
  "top"    => PyObject <matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x31f86e110>
```

showing that `ax[:spines]` is a dictionary. (I did not previously know about this. This is the advantage of having an interactive session -- you can just ask Julia what you need to know. This is called "introspection".)

Following the Python answer linked to in the original question, you then need to replace `ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')` in Python by the following in Julia:

```
ax[:spines]["left"][:set_position]("zero")
```

Again, the `set_position` method inside the object `ax[:spines]["left"]` is called. Note also that strings in Julia must have `"`, not `'`.